# multiple objects to templates with render doesn't work

Tags: django

I have a problem I want to send more than one object to the same page on tamplate but happens with me Problem NoReverseMatch at /

```
def index(request):
    boards=Board.objects.all()
    categorys=Category.objects.all()
    context = {
        'boards':boards ,
        'categorys':categorys,
    }
    return render(request,'home.html',context=context)
```

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='home'),
    path('track/<int:track_id>', views.record_view, name='track1'),

    path('boards/<int:id>', views.boards_topic, name='boards_topic'),

]
```

And Try reversing the order of the last 2 urls and stay problem

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='home'),
    path('', views.category_view, name='home'),
    ...

]
```

```
def index(request):
    boards=Board.objects.all()
    return render(request,'home.html',{'boards':boards})


def category_view(request):
    categorys=Category.objects.all()
    return render(request,'home.html',{'categorys':categorys})
```

What is solution and thank you

Comment: only try this: " return render(request, 'index.html', context)"..don't  return "render(request, 'index.html', context=context)"

Comment: still error NoReverseMatch at / when return render(request,'home.html',context)

Comment: Then you have a problem in the template, which you have not shown. Note, though, that you *cannot* have multiple views with the same URL.

Comment: thank you is right the problem in the template